# How do i loop a code until a certain number is created?

Tags: python, loops, random, python-3.x

This task is to determine the difference between two attributes, strength and skill, from game characters. The process for this is:

- Determining the difference between the strength attributes.
- The difference is divided by five and rounded down to create a ‘strength modifier’.
- The same process is carried out for the skill attribute and named ‘skill modifier’.
- Then the game begins:

  - Both players throw a six sided die.
  - If the values are the same, no changes happen.
  - If the values are different, the player with the highest value then gains the strength and skill worked out earlier and it is then added to their total. The player who has the lowest value has the strength and skill worked out taken away from their total.

This must repeat until the strength attribute is equal or below 0, however, this part I cant do, I know how to loop but this is always done by asking the user if they wish to go again.

```
c1sc=random.randint(1,6)
c2sc=random.randint(1,6)
if c1sc > c2sc:
    c1st=c1st+strengthmodifier
    c2st=c2st-strengthmodifier
    c1sk=c1sk+skillmodifier
    c2sk=c2sk-skillmodifier
    print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
    print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
elif c2sc > c1sc:
    c1st=c1st-strengthmodifier
    c2st=c2st+strengthmodifier
    c1sk=c1sk-skillmodifier
    c2sk=c2sk+skillmodifier
    print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
    print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
else:
    print('It\'s a draw, no changes were made.')
if c1sk < 0:
    c1sk=0
elif c2sk < 0:
    c2sk=0

if c1st < 0:
    print('Character 1 died. Game over.')
elif c2st < 0:
    print('Character 2 died. Game over.')
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you get the picture: (in pseudocode)

```
while (c2sk > 0 && c1sk > 0)
    //do complete everything up until the if statements
if c1st <0
    print "c1st died" 
elif c2st <0
    print "c2st died"
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for exactly. If the c2sk and c1sk is supposed to be randomly reassigned each time it should be inside the loop.

Comment: `while` might never be true - what if they're reduced by 2 every round and start on odd numbers?

Comment: @Basic I see your point. I can't tell if the whole game is supposed to be replayed or just the turn? c1sc supposed to be randomly reassigned each round? cause then it should be inside the loop

Comment: You're not wrong - I've just assumed they kjeep dying at the same rate forever...

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to the `while` loop. You use this when you want something to occur if the specified condition is true or false.

I briefly edited your code.

import random

```
def main():
 player1=20
 player2=12
 strength=(20-10)/5
 strength_mod=int(strength)
 while player1>0 and player2>0:
  dice1=random.randint(1,6)
  dice2=random.randint(1,6)
  if dice1>dice2:
    player1+=strength_mod
    player2-=strength_mod
    print("Player 1 strength is:  ", player1)
    print("Player 2 strength is:  ", player2)
  elif dice1<dice2:
    player2+=strength_mod
    player1-=strength_mod
    print("Player 1 strength is:  ", player1)
    print("Player 2 strength is:  ", player2)

main()
```

I gave players 1 and 2 initial values bet these can be changed to your liking. To round down, I made another variable and changed strength to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Add another loop to do the reductions...

```
c1sc=random.randint(1,6)
c2sc=random.randint(1,6)
if c1sc > c2sc:
    while c2st > 0 and c2sk > 0:
        c1st=c1st+strengthmodifier
        c2st=c2st-strengthmodifier
        c1sk=c1sk+skillmodifier
        c2sk=c2sk-skillmodifier
        print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
        print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
elif c2sc > c1sc:
    while c1st > 0 and c1sk > 0:
        c1st=c1st-strengthmodifier
        c2st=c2st+strengthmodifier
        c1sk=c1sk-skillmodifier
        c2sk=c2sk+skillmodifier
        print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
        print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
else:
    print('It\'s a draw, no changes were made.')
if c1sk < 0:
    c1sk=0
elif c2sk < 0:
    c2sk=0

if c1st < 0:
    print('Character 1 died. Game over.')
elif c2st < 0:
    print('Character 2 died. Game over.')
```

Of course, there are much more compact ways of writing this. This still isn't ideal but is a reduction in code...

```
c1sc=random.randint(1,6)
c2sc=random.randint(1,6)
if c1sc != c2sc:
    while c1st > 0 and and c2st > 0:
        c1st += strengthmodifier if c1sc > c2sc else -1 * strengthmodifier
        c2st += strengthmodifier if c1sc < c2sc else -1 * strengthmodifier
        c1sk += skillmodifier if c1sc > c2sc else -1 * skillmodifier
        c2sk += skillmodifier if c1sc < c2sc else -1 * skillmodifier
        print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
        print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
    c1sk = math.max(c1sk, 0) # Clamp skill to a minimum of 0
    c2sk = math.max(c2sk, 0) # ...

    if c1st < c2st:
        print('Character 1 died. Game over.')
    else:
        print('Character 2 died. Game over.')
else:
    print('It\'s a draw, no changes were made.')
```

And finally, assuming a re-roll every round...

```
while c1st > 0 and and c2st > 0:
    c1sc=random.randint(1,6)
    c2sc=random.randint(1,6)
    if c1sc != c2sc:
        c1st += strengthmodifier if c1sc > c2sc else -1 * strengthmodifier
        c2st += strengthmodifier if c1sc < c2sc else -1 * strengthmodifier
        c1sk += skillmodifier if c1sc > c2sc else -1 * skillmodifier
        c2sk += skillmodifier if c1sc < c2sc else -1 * skillmodifier
        print('Character 1, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c1st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c1sk)))
        print('Character 2, your strength attribute is: '+(str(c2st))+' and your skill attribute is: '+(str(c2sk)))
    else:
        print('It\'s a draw, no changes were made.')


    c1sk = math.max(c1sk, 0) # Clamp skill to a minimum of 0
    c2sk = math.max(c2sk, 0) # ...

if c1st < c2st:
    print('Character 1 died. Game over.')
else:
    print('Character 2 died. Game over.')
```